# How to get only pure value from MySQL

Tags: mysql, node-red

I need value from MySQL send into PLC via OPC UA (in NODE-RED). Everything works ok, but I don't know how to get pure value without descriptions of array etc.

I use this code:

```
SELECT `user_info` FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` LIKE 'Lukas'
```

The answer is:
array[1]
0: object
user_info: "6"

If I send it to PLC as STRING the value in PLC is:

> [object Object]

Can I edit the code somehow? I need answer only:

> 6

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The answer is array[1] 0: object user_info: "6"

I assume you've copied that out of the Debug window which shows you the exact structure of the payload you've received.

That is saying, the payload is an array with a single element. That element is an object with a `user_info` property of value `6`.

In other words:

```
[
    {
        "user_info": "6"
    }
]
```

In which case, to access the value you would use:

```
msg.payload[0].user_info
```

For example, a Function node to pull that value out and put it into the payload would be:

```
msg.payload = msg.payload[0].user_info;
return msg;
```

Or you could use a Change node to set the value of `msg.payload` to the value of `msg.payload[0].user_info`.